Next.js not reflecting updated backend data unless I redeploy on Vercel
I am working with Next.js for the first time and using Axios to fetch data from a backend API. The issue I’m facing is that after I update data in my backend, the changes are not reflected in my app unless I redeploy the app on Vercel. The data I receive seems to be cached or stale, and I can only see the updated data after a redeploy.
Setup:
I have the following code structure:

useData.ts: A custom hook to fetch data using Axios:
import apiClient from "@/services/api-client";
import { AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";

const useData = async <T>(endpoint: string, requestConfig?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T[]> => {
  const maxRetries = 3;
  let attempts = 0;

  while (attempts < maxRetries) {
    try {
      const response = await apiClient.get<T[]>(endpoint, {
        ...requestConfig,
        headers: {
          ...requestConfig?.headers,
        },
      });
      return response.data;
    } catch (error: any) {
      attempts += 1;
      if (attempts === maxRetries) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }
  }

  throw new Error("Failed to fetch data after multiple attempts.");
};

export default useData;


useServices.ts: Uses useData to fetch service data:
import useData from "./useData";

export interface FAQ {
  question: string;
  answer: string;
}

export interface Specialization {
  title: string;
  description: string;
}

export interface Project {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  imageUrl?: string;
  videoUrl?: string;
  projectUrl?: string;
}

export interface Worker {
  title: string;
  description: string;
}

export interface Service {
  slug: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  heroImageUrl?: string;
  heroVideoUrl?: string;
  specialization: Specialization[];
  faq: FAQ[];
  projects: Project[];
  workers: Worker[];
  workersBg: string;
}

const useServices = async () => {
  return await useData<Service>('/services');
};

export default useServices;


Page Component: The main component that uses the useServices hook:
import { Header } from "@/components/Header";
import Footer from "@/components/section/Footer";
import ServicesHero from "@/components/section/servicesHero";
import Specialization from "@/components/section/Specialization";
import TeamWorkers from "@/components/section/TeamWorkers";
import Guide from "./Guide";
import FAQ from "@/components/section/FAQ";
import useServices from "@/hooks/useServices";
import useInfos from "@/hooks/useInfo";
import Projects from "./Projects";

const Animation2dService = async () => {
  const data = await useServices();
  const infos = await useInfos();
  const service = data.find((d) => d.slug === "2d-animation");
  if (!service) return <>Not Found</>;
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {service.heroVideoUrl && <ServicesHero src={service.heroVideoUrl} title={service.title} />}
      <Specialization data={service.specialization} />
      <Guide />
      <TeamWorkers tasks={service.workers} backgroundImg={service.workersBg} />
      {service.projects.length > 0 && <Projects projects={service.projects}/>}
      <FAQ faq={service.faq} />
      <Footer infos={infos[0]} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Animation2dService;



Problem:

When I update my backend (e.g., update data in a database), the changes don’t show up on my Next.js app immediately.
The data fetched from the API is only updated after I redeploy the app on Vercel.
I suspect that caching is involved, but I’m unsure how to prevent it.

What I’ve Tried:

I don’t have any explicit caching mechanisms in my useData.ts or useServices.ts hooks.
I have tried to add headers with Cache-Control: no-store but still facing the same issue.
I also checked the browser dev tools and confirmed that the browser is caching the response.
I even tried to add export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic' to my components, bbut this make my app so slow when naviging.

Question:

How can I ensure that the data from the backend is always up-to-date when fetching from my Next.js app, especially when it is hosted on Vercel?
Are there any caching mechanisms I need to consider on Vercel or the Next.js app that might be causing this issue?
Do I need to disable or configure ISR (Incremental Static Regeneration) or SSR (Server-Side Rendering) in a specific way to ensure that the data is always freshly fetched from the backend?

Any guidance or advice on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!
